# Getting a string conversion error when trying to exclude a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

So, I'm still learning the ins and outs of SQL and I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
SELECT P.productid, P.productname, O.orderdate
FROM Production.Products AS P INNER JOIN
Sales.OrderDetails AS D ON P.productid = D.productid
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS O ON D.orderid = O.orderid
WHERE (O.orderdate NOT BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-31');
```

It produces the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: fwiw NOT BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-31' wont exclude the whole month you need to go from the 1st to the 1st if you're using between

Comment: This is the error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Icodin where do those values come from? Raw strings, date parameters? Do you always intend to match a whole month? The fix for the typo is easy. Making the query resilient to such problems requires a few more details. Eg, if the value is a string, don't use a string, use `date` parameters. Use EOMONTH to get the last day of the month for any parameter.

Comment: No knowledge of SQL required. No programming language worth its salt should recognise `2015-09-31` as a valid date.

Comment: Sorry for not catching this sooner. I apologize for wasting everyone's time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `orderdate` is a date/datetime, the error you should be getting is:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

It is because **September has 30 days, not 31**. Change to `2018-09-30`.

Or better, use `EOMONTH()` function:

```
SELECT EOMONTH('2019-02-01')
-- 2019-02-28
SELECT EOMONTH('2020-02-01')
-- 2020-02-29 because 2020 is a leap year
```

Or even better, do not use `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE NOT (O.orderdate >= '2015-09-01' AND O.orderdate < '2015-10-01')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry I wasted everyone's time and not catching this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-09-01', @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@Date))), @EndDate = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@Date)), @Date) AS DATE)

SELECT P.productid, P.productname, O.orderdate
FROM Production.Products AS P INNER JOIN
Sales.OrderDetails AS D ON P.productid = D.productid
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS O ON D.orderid = O.orderid
WHERE (O.orderdate NOT BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate);
```

at Line 1 declare 3 date variables @Date, @StartDate, @EndDate and assign value a random date to @Date like '2018-09-01'
at Line 2 wrt to @Date, getting start and end date as variable.
at Line 3 in where clause add those dates

Solution: by these steps you never get a error date start and end date because here you provide only one random date and in return you have 2 dates containing start and end date of Year+Month.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you to avoid using `BETWEEN` (and `NOT BETWEEN`) with date/time data types.  Aaron Bertrand has a very good blog explaining the reasoning, [What do Between and the Devil have in Common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

```
SELECT P.productid, P.productname, O.orderdate
FROM Production.Products P INNER JOIN
     Sales.OrderDetails D
     ON P.productid = D.productid INNER JOIN
     Sales.Orders O
     ON D.orderid = O.orderid
WHERE O.orderdate < '2015-09-01' OR
      O.orderdate >= '2015-10-01';
```